# Can I install ros into a ARM chip?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a ARM A9 chip, and i can run a ubuntu in the chip .
So can i install the ROS into the chip?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51074/can-i-install-ros-into-a-arm-chip?/) by [Robin Hu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3839/robin-hu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2012-12-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-12-26**:
Which kind of board do you use? Pandaboard or beagleboard?

**Comment by [Robin Hu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3839/robin-hu/) on 2012-12-26**:
I use the Zynq board producted by xilinx. There are two A9 cores in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, but you will need to build it yourself from source. Willow Garage no longer supplies pre-built ARM binaries.

The [EROS project](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros) may be helpful.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0